# Display Instagram Follower Count With PHP

Tags: php, instagram

Trying to use this code provided by an article to pull and display user data. All I am manage to get so far is

Username not found.

```
<?php
$username = 'burhandodhy';

$response = @file_get_contents( "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" );

if ( $response !== false ) {
    $data = json_decode( $response, true );
    if ( $data !== null ) {
        $full_name = $data['graphql']['user']['full_name'];
        $follower  = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
        echo "{$full_name} have {$follower} followers.";
    }

} else {
    echo 'Username not found.';

}
?>
```

When I visit the link in @file_get_contents I see a lot of info about the users but I am not familiar with PHP and other languages of this type. Can someone please point me in the right direction of what to research or send me a quick fix if this code should work and there's just an error.

Thanks,
Brian

Added this code into a file called

instagram.php

on my WordPress website.

I just want to learn how to display the info in `https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1`
on my website.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is a PHP function and should be used as `$result = file_get_contents(string);`. You need to change `@file_get_contents` with just `file_get_contents`. Also take a look at the Instagram API [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/).

Comment: Humm, still not working. Maybe this will help me learn what to learn better. What would you call this info on https://www.instagram.com/nike/?__a=1 ? Is this json? Would this be easier to pull with JS?

Comment: It is JSON, but seeing I can't access this data without being logged in, you'd need to include a cookie to view this data (which is not feasible in this situation). I recommend you use the Instagram API, which uses an authentication token.

Comment: Will I still be able to search other accounts info with the api? Also, to use the API with WordPress do you recommend PHP?

Comment: I'd use PHP yeah. In the Instagram API docs you can find information on how to query other accounts.

Comment: "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" solution works but after some weeks, instagram blocks that domain thus system does not able to fetch followers count to display on our website. I faced this issue on 2 domains/websites.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to concatenate the variable into the link.

```
$response = @file_get_contents( "https://www.instagram.com/**".$username."**/?__a=1" );
```

But besides that, I don't believe the link will work unless you are authenticated through Instagram anyways.

Comment: Concatenation is not necessary.

Comment: @ceejayoz elaborate? doesn't work without concatenating for me on my scripts that look exactly the same?

Comment: `"https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1"` is perfectly fine syntax that will be correctly interpreted. The concatenation is not necessary. (I tested, incidentally.) The other part of your answer - that you need to be logged in to access this endpoint - appears to be correct.

Comment: I don't see how? I have this line `        $d = file_get_contents('https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names='.$t);` Which doesnt work without the . before the $t? Alos, really sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: You should look into the difference between `'` and `"` in PHP.

Comment: @ceejayoz "instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" solution works but after some weeks, instagram blocks that domain thus system does not able to fetch followers count to display on our website. I faced this issue on 2 domains/websites.

Comment: @Kamlesh Yes, violating the Instagram Terms of Service will get you blocked eventually.